# How can I have a background not cover every button, label?

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I am making an app with a background that leaves a big blank white space at the top of the screen when I use the first code shown below and as soon as I add `self.view.addSubview(image view)` at the end of this code like the second piece of code it covers all my labels and buttons, how can I have it so that it takes up the whole screen like in the second part but doesn't cover up the buttons like in the first piece of code?
thanks !

first code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let yourImage = UIImage(named: "fond320x480.png")
        let imageview = UIImageView(image: yourImage)
        self.view.addSubview(imageview)
        self.view.sendSubviewToBack(imageview)
        imageview.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
        imageview.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
        imageview.frame = self.view.bounds
```

second code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let yourImage = UIImage(named: "fond320x480.png")
        let imageview = UIImageView(image: yourImage)
        self.view.addSubview(imageview)
        self.view.sendSubviewToBack(imageview)
        imageview.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
        imageview.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
        imageview.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.addSubview(imageview)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to send it to the back using this method
insertSubview:yourSubView atIndex:0
and give it the index by zero.

or use this one 
 -insertSubview:aboveSubview:

the other solution is to add all your view in one view and then add the image and use method -belowSubView- to add the image under the view that has all your views

hope this answer can help good luck

Comment: Do I simply add these at the end of that bit of code? I tried doing this, it told me to add (;) instead of (:) and it gives me an error saying "swift compiler error expected expression"

Comment: @stephenD add it like this  self.view.insertSubview(image view, belowSubview: -the view that your view in it -);

Comment: What do you mean by the view that you view it in? is it the name of the view controller?

Comment: This is the line of code I have been typing: self.view.insertSubview(image view, belowSubview:self.view and it asks me to put a "," in 5 different places, as well as expected expression in list of expressions in the line were I have "}" any ideas as to why?

Comment: can you show me the code you write its like you missed something @stephenD

Comment: This is my code : override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let yourImage = UIImage(named: "fond320x480.png")
        let imageview = UIImageView(image: yourImage)
        self.view.addSubview(imageview)
        self.view.sendSubviewToBack(imageview)
        imageview.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
        imageview.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
        imageview.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.addSubview(imageview)
        self.view.insertSubview(image view, belowSubview:self.view